# EOL compatibility on BOTH Linux and Dos/Windows servers?

Tags: php, wamp, newline, notepad++, lamp

Using **Notepad++** on a windows box, (*100s of files into a plugin I've been developing for Wordpress*) [I bumped up against a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16547487/wordpress-ajax-setcookie-wamp-lamp-disparities/16568666#16568666) wherein the differences in newline characters between Linux and Dos/Windows causes some of my scripts to break when hosted on a LAMP server, which otherwise work fine on my WAMP Dev Server. Reading up on **[Notepad++ EOL Conversion](https://superuser.com/questions/479756/eol-in-notepad-and-notepad)**, one might infer that a different code base must be maintained for each, but surely that's not the case?

1. How does one ensure EOL compatibility on BOTH Linux and Dos/Windows servers?
2. How best to bring 100's of files into compliance?

Comment: you can use the linux command `dos2unix` or `unix2dos` depending on what you want to do.

Comment: Our LAMP servers all work fine with windows line endings, unix line endings and in some cases :( a combination of both in the same file. Are you sure it is not something else, eg. your paths `/` instead of ``\`` which are causing the problem rather than the line endings.

Comment: In context, as a plugin for wordpress it is unrealistic to ask the average user to 1. Determine whether what flavor of server their site is hosted on, or... 2. Start issuing bash commands

Comment: @Anigel 
Well... it struck me as odd too, but if you follow my original post on the problem I think you might agree that this seems to be the case? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16547487/wordpress-ajax-setcookie-wamp-lamp-disparities/16568666#16568666

Comment: I've come accross this problem, however it was when the php files where imported into netbeans on a linux machine and then downloaded to a windows machine, it does not recognise the line endings so returned a 500 error.